# How to return a file fetched with promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise, return, fetch-api

What I have tried is this:

```
function getEventFileFromServer () {
  const fetchedPromise = fetch('event-file.txt');
  fetchedPromise.then(eventFile => eventFile.text())
  .then(contentOfEventFile => {
    return contentOfEventFile;
  });
}

console.log(getEventFileFromServer()) // logs 'undefined'
```

If I do `console.log(contentOfEventFile)` instead of `return contentOfEventFile`, I can see the content of the file in the console, but I how can I return it to use it in a different function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that fetching the file is an asynchronous event and the function returned undefined before your promise resolves. Consider it like this -

```
function getEventFileFromServer () {
  const fetchedPromise = fetch('event-file.txt');
  fetchedPromise.then(eventFile => eventFile.text())
  .then(contentOfEventFile => {
    return contentOfEventFile;
  });
  return undefined;
}
```

Now, you have couple of options.

1.) Async/Await

```
async function getEventFileFromServer () {
  const eventFile = await fetch('event-file.txt');
  const contentOfFile = await eventFile.text();
  return contentOfFile;
}
```

then use it wherever you want with `async/await` or promise i.e. -

```
async useFileValue() {
    const data = await getEventFileFromServer();
    console.log(data);
}
```

2.) Returning the promise itself -

Instead of using `.then` on the promise, simply return the promise i.e. -

```
function getFileEvent() {
     return fetch('event-file.txt');
}
```

and now get the value resolved by promise wherever you want by using `.then`

```
function getFileData() {
    getFileEvent().then(eventFile => eventFile.text())
                  .then(contentOfEventFile => {
                      // Do whatever you want with data here
                      console.log(contentOfEventFile);
                  })
}
```